# Anti-aliasing while rendering to texture in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, libgdx, antialiasing, fbo, msaa

I am rendering my scene into a texture so that I can apply post-processing before displaying the final result.  However, when I added this feature, MSAA/CSAA stopped working.  Is there a way (other than performance intensive FSAA) to get anti-aliasing to work?

I am targeting multiple platforms (android 2.2+, iphone 3gs+, all ipads), so I am looking for a way to do this without requiring extensions (unless they are ubiquitous).

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603779/with-opengl-es-2-0-on-android-is-there-a-way-preserve-multisampling-when-render?rq=1?

Comment: P.T., that is exactly what I needed to see (but hoped not to see).  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MSAA works by default on default frame buffer only. You should use multisample textures .This thread can be helpful:
 [Multisampled render to texture in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402504/multisampled-render-to-texture-in-ios)